# What does "please with sugar and knobs on" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *please with sugar and knobs on* mean in the following sentence?

> Please, pretty please, pretty **please with sugar and knobs on**, do not
>   ever look at your monthly/quarterly/annual statements; they only serve
>   to confuse you.

Specifically, what do *sugar* and *knob* refer to?

This comes from a [comment](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/net-loss-not-distributed-by-mutual-funds-to-their-shareholders#comment19905_15290) on Money SE.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/net-loss-not-distributed-by-mutual-funds-to-their-shareholders#comment19905_15290

Comment: He called "please" pretty instead.

Comment: @Tim: Since you have an account at Money SE, could you ask Dilip about this phrase in a comment and point him to this discussion? Maybe he could tell us what he meant and whether or not he made up this phrase or has heard it used before.

Comment: As Rory Alsop and FumbleFingers said, the "knobs" in this case has nothing to do with food, and everything to do with embellishment. (In fact, my first thought was *knobs* = *buttons*, as in big, red, and shiny, just begging to be pressed. Let's just say, my not-quite-2-year-old niece is not the only person who is enamored of all things button-like.)

Comment: @Callithumpian: Your and J.R.'s requests have made the author come here and leave an explanation.

Comment: The person making the request is asking "with sugar and knobs" asking the person to do it AS IF you would desire to eat, let's say, berries even more with the added sugar. OR " and knobs" doing it with the draw or desire of the moth to a flame, to touch something that looks ultra soft, do desire it more with the added bling, THE ADDED KNOB.... get it???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's three different "intensifiers" used together, effectively *"Please please please **please**!"*

**Pretty** as in [that was pretty stupid](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pretty%20much%20died%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_nf=1&ds=bo&pq=%22pretty%20stupid%22&cp=10&gs_id=2z&xhr=t&q=%22that%20was%20pretty%20stupid%22&pf=p&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22that%20was%20pretty%20stupid%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1fba3d7991298238&biw=1258&bih=842) is quite common in the slightly childish/winsome/wheedling entreaty [Pretty please?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22pretty%20much%20died%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22pretty%20please%22&oq=%22pretty%20please%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...112939.117018.3.117601.15.15.0.0.0.0.96.992.15.15.0...0.0.XMjnW_DEdUQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1fba3d7991298238&biw=1258&bih=842).

[With [brass] knobs on](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/with-brass-knobs-on) is a well-established intensifier (cf [with bells on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+bells+on)). I've not come across **with sugar** used in this way, and certainly the conjunction of all three isn't what I'd call a standard idiom, but in context the meaning is obvious.

EDIT: Note that ["The same to you with [brass] knobs on!"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-the-same-to-you-with-knobs-on) is (rather dated) ***British*** slang, which explains why many people aren't familiar with it. Outside of that specific retort, *with knobs on* was never particularly common, so for any one under 50 (or not British) I've obviously overstated the case by saying it's a *"well-established intensifier"*. Nevertheless, it is just an intensifier, with no other connection to *"pretty"* and *"with sugar on"*.

Comment: Thanks,but I don't understand why adding a knob or bell makes a thing extreme. I can feel the emphasis, but not from the metaphor by sugar and knob on

Comment: @Tim: They're just slangy metaphoric idiomatic usages. With *sugar* because sugar is a desirable extra "sweetener bribe" added to the entreaty. And *with knobs on* meaning *with adornments* - again, simply providing emphasis. They're idiomatic usages, so it's not really important to understand *why* they have this sense - the fact is that native speakers are normally familiar with both anyway, because they're used this way in other contexts (not so much *with sugar*, maybe, but it's just more of the same in this particular case, so the meaning is clear).

Comment: Given the [new information](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70024/5822), I concede part of this argument to you and reverse my downvote of your answer. I would like to point out, however, that this was in fact an accidental combination (and abbreviation) of two very distinct phrases.

Comment: @Callithumpian: ty. I hadn't realised how common *"pretty please **with sugar on**"* is in America, meaning those two are effectively a "set phrase". So you're right that it's better described as a combination of **two** expressions, not three. All three elements are just intensifiers, but Americans are already used to hearing two of them paired up in a *"Please, please, **please**"* construction.

Comment: This seems like an appropriate time to link to this clip from Pulp Fiction, in which one mildly irritated character says *"So pretty please, with sugar on top: clean the f#cking car"*   https://youtu.be/dMRap8SjQ-I?t=115

Answer (score 4):

"With sugar on," indicates you are offering something desirable or valuable as an incentive.

"With knobs on," comes from 1920's slang, and meant that something was embellished, for example an iron bedstead with knobs on becomes that bit more special.

The two phrases together are just meant to accentuate the request, as is the repetition of "pretty," - the request becomes special, different, more important.

Comment: Thanks! (1) You mean "you are offering" or "you are offered"? (2) I still don't get the metaphore. How do sugar and knobs accentuate the request?

Comment: In this instance, the person asking you not to look at your statements is trying to emphasise that fact, and then emphasise even more.

Comment: I still don't get the metaphore. How do sugar and knobs accentuate the request?

Comment: @Tim - see my edit. Does that help?

Comment: @Tim: The *sugar* and *knobs* don't directly relate to the request - they're (to a greater or lesser extent) established idiomatic intensifiers in other contexts, and the preceding well-established intensifier ***pretty** please* clearly signals what role those additions play, even to people who've not heard them used in precisely this context before.

Comment: @RoryAlsop "With knobs on" is like saying "with bells on," and we wouldn't say "pretty please with sugar and bells on top." As "pretty please with sugar on top" seems to be the earliest form of the phrase, food metaphors are the most common (cherry on top, whipped cream on top, etc.). (edited) Looks like a mixed metaphor per FumbleFingers.

Comment: @choster - exactly! That was the whole point of my answer - 3 mixed embellishments.

Comment: @RoryAlsop:Thanks,but I don't  understand how the metaphor works.

Comment: @Tim, It doesn't work for me either. They just mean "please, please, please, pleeeeeeeeease do not ever look...." They just threw in [everything but the kitchen sink.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/everything+but+the+kitchen+sink) (Do you know that cliche?)

Comment: @JLG: THanks, but I dont know the cliche.

Comment: @choster: I'm not sure I'd call it a "mixed metaphor" as such. But it does seem that people who don't know *"with knobs on"* are inclined to assume this somehow relates to *"with sugar"*, and must therefore be an allusion to scrumptious food. That's to say they're *looking* for a coherent metaphoric link between the three intensifiers, when in fact they're just three unrelated idiomatic ways of conveying emphatic pleading.

Answer (score 4):

As the one who perpetrated the phrase that has created such vigorous discussion,
let me begin by saying that although I have spoken English for most of my
life (even attended and matriculated (O level GCE from Cambridge) from 
what is called an English-medium school in India), I am not a native speaker 
of English, and the language that I speak and write is a mishmash of American
and British English with a few phrases from Indglish thrown in.

@callithumpian's suggestion "...the original comment was an accidental mash-up of these two..." is dead on target: I mashed up two intensifiers, perhaps accidentally, but more likely because of a failure to do a final
proof-reading after editing my comment to fit the length constraint 
imposed by stackexchange (I deleted a lot of extraneous stuff). 
The "Please, pretty please, with sugar" and the 
elided "on top" is from my life in the US and 
I learned to use it while wheedling my children and 
grandchildren and their friends.  The "knobs on" 
part is 
definitely from my reading during my schooldays 
(fifty years ago!) which was almost
exclusively of British authors with the exception of Mark Twain.
I might be remembering the phrase from a P. G. Wodehouse novel or 
story or even from a Billy Bunter story. I have always understood "with knobs
on" as meaning embellishment or adornment and not as referring to knobs 
(or gobs) of butter. I wanted to make my plea to OP Tim to ignore 
certain pieces of paper more emphatic, and mixed up two phrases
in my hurry to do so:
knobs on certainly does not seem applicable to sugar -- on top
or elsewhere.

I think it is the first time that something I have written has 
led to a top-ranked hit on Google. Oh, that any of my
intentional writings were so fortunate!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write. Your expression made a lot of us scratch our heads and speculate (starting with the O.P.), and led to a most interesting discussion. As for me, I learned about _knobs of butter_, and the _knobs on_ idiom, so that's a net +2 for me.

Answer (score 3):

See also ["Pretty please with sugar on top"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31530/pretty-please-with-sugar-on-top) .

As you know *please* is a modifier for making a request polite, and by implication making it more likely to be fulfilled. A child, for example, might take this "magic" quality of *please*  and try to dress up the phrase. *Pretty please* indicates more urgent pleading. *Pretty please with cherries on top* is rather abject. Anything desirable "topping" could be suggested here, as one would add to ice cream or pancakes and the like: sugar, syrup, or in this case *knobs* probably meaning a [knob of butter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-much-is-a-knob-of-butter).

"Knobs" is not a common measurement in American English; usually it is a vulgarism for breasts or nipples.

Comment: knobs in this context were not anything to do with food - see my edit to my answer. And it definitely isn't used in Britain to mean breasts or nipples - it is used to mean penis, as Clark commented.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Not at all - *knobs* here means *with **adornments**, with all the trimmings, augmented, amplified*. Nothing to do with food *or* genitalia.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I know that. See my answer - nothing to do with food or genitalia. I must be having a bad English day - that's me being misunderstood by you and choster... ah well.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: oic. Me too. I see what you meant now. *Knob* is indeed UK slang (esp., childish) for *penis* - but not in this particular case, as your answer indicates.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard  *pretty please with sugar on top* since I was a youngster.  It's is a fairly common (and somewhat childish) way of pleading with someone:

[image]

I've never heard the "with sugar and knobs" variation, not until today.  Based on a quick Google search, though, it appears to be nothing more than a simple variant on the "sweet topping" motif; *knobs* apparently refers to gobs of butter:

[image]

How much butter is in a knob of butter?  That's a question for a [different](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/how-much-is-a-knob-of-butter) StackExchange.

Comment: Finally, an answer that seems to make sense.

Comment: Didn't I essentially say same thing? Apparently RoryAlsop is not the only one having trouble getting understood today.

Comment: @choster: You did. Not sure why you got downvotes. Maybe you should throw in some sexy screenshots.

Comment: It's *nothing to do with "knobs" of butter*. The "knobs" here is a long-established idiom for "with adornments" (i.e. - with *buttons, bells, whistles,* etc.).

Comment: @Callithumpian, choster: I downvoted both these answers, and it's nothing to do with screenshots. Rory's answer correctly points out the significance of *"with knobs on"* - these speculations about "knobs of butter" are completely spurious, and shouldn't be allowed to stand unchallenged.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The screenshot comment was a joke, of course. _With sugar on top_ is as familiar to some of us as _with knobs on_ is to you. Either the original comment was an accidental mash-up of these two or the _knobs_ do in fact refer to something else yummy piled on top of the _please_. I'm open to the possibility that you're right, but given the lack of corroboration here, I think you should be open to the possibility that you're wrong. J.R. has kindly asked the comment's OP what he thinks he meant, so we may soon get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Not quite sure what you mean there. Unquestionably, *with [brass] knobs on* is a long-established idiom that has nothing to do with food. Possibly the author of the specific instance quoted by OP was unaware of this (obviously some people here aren't familiar with it), but I don't see how that would make me "wrong". Bear in mind that [same to you with knobs on](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/and-the-same-to-you-with-knobs-on) is a **Briticism**, so this ignorance is no surprise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not questioning the legitimacy or meaning of _with knobs on_. I'm just saying that there is a possibility that this comment was actually a Briticization of the more American _pretty please, with sugar on top_ and that the unabbreviated meaning is _pretty please with sugar and knobs [of butter] on [top]_ and has nothing to do with brass knobs. As J.R. has shown, _with sugar and knobs of butter_ is a repeated and understood phrase among British bakers.

Comment: @Callithumpian: If you and others insist on envisaging allusions to *knobs of butter* I guess there's nothing I can say to convince you otherwise. As I said, for all I know the original speaker was under the same misapprehension anyway - in which case perhaps it's best described as an "eggcorn" or a "mixed metaphor". But I will just say the whole entreaty is a typically "childish" form, but normally only ***adults*** talking about cooking would use the term *knobs of butter* in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Spurious, you say? Aw, you know me better than that! ;^) Any time I've heard "pretty please with sugar on top," the imagery has been of a heaping gooey sweet topping on the "Please Sundae," usually just sugar, but sometimes whipped cream and a cherry, too. Like Callithumpian, I'll grant you that "knobs on" means adornments (that's well-established), but I'm having trouble finding any use of that expression tied to "sugar" – people just don't put _sugar_ on their knobs unless we're talking about [knobs of butter](http://www.google.com/#q=%22sugar+and+knobs%22&hl=en&safe=active).

Comment: @J.R.: Since you're American, I suppose you're just trying to come up with what seems like a "reasonable" meaning for these knobs given you didn't know the standard British usage (which hasn't been common for decades anyway). I can only pronounce on the *original usage/meaning* - exactly how people [choose to] interpret allusions (spuriously or otherwise) isn't something others can dictate.

Comment: @Fumble, I may have an inferior American education ;^) but I've reviewed every reference to "knobs" you've provided, and none of them seem to fit into the context of "pretty please with sugar and knobs." Had the quote been "pretty please with trinkets and knobs" or "pretty please with bells and knobs" or "pretty please with polish and knobs" or "pretty please with bedknobs and broomsticks" I would have zealously upvoted your answer and kept my nob shut. But "pretty please with sugar and knobs" makes it seem at least an eggcorn, as you said. Anyway, it's been an enjoyable question & discussion.

Comment: @J.R.: Your request has made the author come here and leave an explanation.